# Spring XML using <bean>

Tags: spring, spring-security

This is a pretty simple question, I'm following a tutorial and I'm up to the point where I'm adding a passwordEncoder to my spring security, I have the following XML...

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/static/**" security="none" />
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/secure/extreme/**" access="hasRole('supervisor')" 
            /> -->
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/listAccounts.html" access="isAuthenticated()" 
            /> -->
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/post.html" access="hasAnyRole('supervisor','teller')" 
            /> -->
<!--        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="denyAll" /> -->
        <form-login />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/"
            logout-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
          <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

</beans:beans>
```

The problem is the `<bean class="org.spr..` line just at the bottom is erroring saying security namespace does not allow

I do understand this, but is there a way I can use the reference without having to add `<security:` to everything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XML declaration you are declaring that "security:" is the default namespace:

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
```

you have to preface all the elements not found in the security namespace with their prefix... in this case bean is in beans namespace... so you would need to say, beans:bean

Answer (score 2):

This declaration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>
```

should be:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>
```